# Unity Failed running C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp/build/il2cpp.exe --convert-to-cpp --emit-null-checks

Tags: unity-game-engine

I try to build a game for google play and when i use IL2CPP to build for 32 and 64 bit i get this error:
Failed running C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp/build/il2cpp.exe --convert-to-cpp --emit-null-checks --enable-array-bounds-check --dotnetprofile="unityaot" --compile-cpp --libil2cpp-static --platform="Android" --architecture="ARMv7" --configuration="Release" --outputpath="D:\Unity\Test\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Native\armeabi-v7a\libil2cpp.so" --cachedirectory="D:\Unity\Test\Assets..\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a/il2cpp_cache" --additional-include-directories="C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\bdwgc/include" --additional-include-directories="C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\libil2cpp/include" --tool-chain-path="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.1.1f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK" --profiler-report --map-file-parser="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.1.1f1/Editor/Data/Tools/MapFileParser/MapFileParser.exe" --directory=D:/Unity/Test/Temp/StagingArea/assets/bin/Data/Managed --generatedcppdir=D:/Unity/Test/Temp/StagingArea/Il2Cpp/il2cppOutput

stdout:

Building libil2cpp.so with AndroidToolChain

```
Output directory: D:\Unity\Test\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Native\armeabi-v7a

Cache directory: D:\Unity\Test\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a\il2cpp_cache
```

il2cpp.exe didn't catch exception: Unity.IL2CPP.Building.BuilderFailedException: In file included from D:\Unity\Test\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput\lumpedcpp\Lump_libil2cpp_os.cpp:72:

In file included from C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\libil2cpp\os\Unity\AtomicQueue.cpp:6:

In file included from C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\libil2cpp\os\Unity/ExtendedAtomicOps.h:121:

C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\libil2cpp\os\Unity/ExtendedAtomicOps-arm.h:622:17: error: asm-specifier for input or output variable conflicts with asm clobber list

```
    : "cc", "r2", "r3"

            ^
```

C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\libil2cpp\os\Unity/ExtendedAtomicOps-arm.h:653:27: error: asm-specifier for input or output variable conflicts with asm clobber list

```
    : "cc", "memory", "r2", "r3"

                      ^
```

C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\libil2cpp\os\Unity/ExtendedAtomicOps-arm.h:690:27: error: asm-specifier for input or output variable conflicts with asm clobber list

```
    : "cc", "memory", "r2", "r3"

                      ^
```

C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\libil2cpp\os\Unity/ExtendedAtomicOps-arm.h:724:27: error: asm-specifier for input or output variable conflicts with asm clobber list

```
    : "cc", "memory", "r2", "r3"

                      ^
```

C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\libil2cpp\os\Unity/ExtendedAtomicOps-arm.h:755:27: error: asm-specifier for input or output variable conflicts with asm clobber list

```
    : "cc", "memory", "r0", "r1", "r3"

                      ^
```

C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\libil2cpp\os\Unity/ExtendedAtomicOps-arm.h:793:27: error: asm-specifier for input or output variable conflicts with asm clobber list

```
    : "cc", "memory", "r2", "r3"

                      ^
```

C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\libil2cpp\os\Unity/ExtendedAtomicOps-arm.h:833:27: error: asm-specifier for input or output variable conflicts with asm clobber list

```
    : "cc", "memory", "r2", "r3"

                      ^
```

C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\libil2cpp\os\Unity/ExtendedAtomicOps-arm.h:875:27: error: asm-specifier for input or output variable conflicts with asm clobber list

```
    : "cc", "memory", "r2", "r3"

                      ^
```

C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\libil2cpp\os\Unity/ExtendedAtomicOps-arm.h:917:27: error: asm-specifier for input or output variable conflicts with asm clobber list

```
    : "cc", "memory", "r2", "r3"

                      ^
```

9 errors generated.

Invocation was: Executable: "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++"

Arguments: -DNET_4_0 -DUNITY_AOT -DGC_NOT_DLL -DRUNTIME_IL2CPP -DLINUX -DANDROID -DPLATFORM_ANDROID -D__linux__ -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -I"C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\bdwgc\include" -I"C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\libil2cpp\include" -I"C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\libil2cpp" -I"C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\libil2cpp" -I"C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\external\bdwgc\include" -I"." -I"C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\sources\cxx-stl\llvm-libc++\include" -I"C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\sources\cxx-stl\llvm-libc++abi\include" -I"C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\sources\android\support\include" -c -g -DNDEBUG -fexceptions -fno-limit-debug-info -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wa,--noexecstack -fno-rtti -std=c++98 -fno-strict-aliasing -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fno-strict-overflow -fPIC -Os --sysroot "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\sysroot" -gcc-toolchain "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64" -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi -isystem "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\sysroot\usr\include\arm-linux-androideabi" -D__ANDROID_API__=16 -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon-fp16 -Wno-unused-value "D:\Unity\Test\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput\lumpedcpp\Lump_libil2cpp_os.cpp" -o "D:/Unity/Test/Library/il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a/il2cpp_cache/libil2cpp/3D9E94D82FD7A3405B7E78EF705BF052.o"

at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.BuildAllCppFiles(IEnumerable`1 sourceFilesToCompile, IBuildStatisticsCollector statisticsCollector)

at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.Build(IBuildStatistics& statistics)

at il2cpp.Program.DoRun(String[] args)

at il2cpp.Program.Run(String[] args)

at il2cpp.Program.Main(String[] args)

stderr:

Unhandled Exception: Unity.IL2CPP.Building.BuilderFailedException: In file included from D:\Unity\Test\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput\lumpedcpp\Lump_libil2cpp_os.cpp:72:

In file included from C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\libil2cpp\os\Unity\AtomicQueue.cpp:6:

In file included from C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\libil2cpp\os\Unity/ExtendedAtomicOps.h:121:

C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\libil2cpp\os\Unity/ExtendedAtomicOps-arm.h:622:17: error: asm-specifier for input or output variable conflicts with asm clobber list

```
    : "cc", "r2", "r3"

            ^
```

C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\libil2cpp\os\Unity/ExtendedAtomicOps-arm.h:653:27: error: asm-specifier for input or output variable conflicts with asm clobber list

```
    : "cc", "memory", "r2", "r3"

                      ^
```

C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\libil2cpp\os\Unity/ExtendedAtomicOps-arm.h:690:27: error: asm-specifier for input or output variable conflicts with asm clobber list

```
    : "cc", "memory", "r2", "r3"

                      ^
```

C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\libil2cpp\os\Unity/ExtendedAtomicOps-arm.h:724:27: error: asm-specifier for input or output variable conflicts with asm clobber list

```
    : "cc", "memory", "r2", "r3"

                      ^
```

C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\libil2cpp\os\Unity/ExtendedAtomicOps-arm.h:755:27: error: asm-specifier for input or output variable conflicts with asm clobber list

```
    : "cc", "memory", "r0", "r1", "r3"

                      ^
```

C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\libil2cpp\os\Unity/ExtendedAtomicOps-arm.h:793:27: error: asm-specifier for input or output variable conflicts with asm clobber list

```
    : "cc", "memory", "r2", "r3"

                      ^
```

C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\libil2cpp\os\Unity/ExtendedAtomicOps-arm.h:833:27: error: asm-specifier for input or output variable conflicts with asm clobber list

```
    : "cc", "memory", "r2", "r3"

                      ^
```

C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\libil2cpp\os\Unity/ExtendedAtomicOps-arm.h:875:27: error: asm-specifier for input or output variable conflicts with asm clobber list

```
    : "cc", "memory", "r2", "r3"

                      ^
```

C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\libil2cpp\os\Unity/ExtendedAtomicOps-arm.h:917:27: error: asm-specifier for input or output variable conflicts with asm clobber list

```
    : "cc", "memory", "r2", "r3"

                      ^
```

9 errors generated.

Invocation was: Executable: "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++"

Arguments: -DNET_4_0 -DUNITY_AOT -DGC_NOT_DLL -DRUNTIME_IL2CPP -DLINUX -DANDROID -DPLATFORM_ANDROID -D__linux__ -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -I"C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\bdwgc\include" -I"C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\libil2cpp\include" -I"C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\libil2cpp" -I"C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\libil2cpp" -I"C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\external\bdwgc\include" -I"." -I"C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\sources\cxx-stl\llvm-libc++\include" -I"C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\sources\cxx-stl\llvm-libc++abi\include" -I"C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\sources\android\support\include" -c -g -DNDEBUG -fexceptions -fno-limit-debug-info -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wa,--noexecstack -fno-rtti -std=c++98 -fno-strict-aliasing -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fno-strict-overflow -fPIC -Os --sysroot "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\sysroot" -gcc-toolchain "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64" -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi -isystem "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\sysroot\usr\include\arm-linux-androideabi" -D__ANDROID_API__=16 -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon-fp16 -Wno-unused-value "D:\Unity\Test\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput\lumpedcpp\Lump_libil2cpp_os.cpp" -o "D:/Unity/Test/Library/il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a/il2cpp_cache/libil2cpp/3D9E94D82FD7A3405B7E78EF705BF052.o"

at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.BuildAllCppFiles(IEnumerable`1 sourceFilesToCompile, IBuildStatisticsCollector statisticsCollector)

at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.Build(IBuildStatistics& statistics)

at il2cpp.Program.DoRun(String[] args)

at il2cpp.Program.Run(String[] args)

at il2cpp.Program.Main(String[] args)

UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
UnityEditorInternal.Runner:RunProgram(Program, String, String, String, CompilerOutputParserBase) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:128)
UnityEditorInternal.Runner:RunManagedProgram(String, String, String, CompilerOutputParserBase, Action`1) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:73)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:RunIl2CppWithArguments(List`1, Action`1, String) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:496)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:ConvertPlayerDlltoCpp(String, String, String, Boolean) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:477)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:Run() (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:334)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils:RunIl2Cpp(String, String, IIl2CppPlatformProvider, Action`1, RuntimeClassRegistry) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:63)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Exception: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.1f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp/build/il2cpp.exe did not run properly!
UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunProgram (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:130)
UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunManagedProgram (System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser, System.Action`1[T] setupStartInfo) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:73)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.RunIl2CppWithArguments (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] arguments, System.Action`1[T] setupStartInfo, System.String workingDirectory) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:496)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.ConvertPlayerDlltoCpp (System.String inputDirectory, System.String outputDirectory, System.String workingDirectory, System.Boolean platformSupportsManagedDebugging) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:477)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.Run () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:334)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils.RunIl2Cpp (System.String tempFolder, System.String stagingAreaData, UnityEditorInternal.IIl2CppPlatformProvider platformProvider, System.Action`1[T] modifyOutputBeforeCompile, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry runtimeClassRegistry) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:63)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.RunIl2Cpp.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <177bc8179be6497489c4b5b319f290d7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <177bc8179be6497489c4b5b319f290d7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <177bc8179be6497489c4b5b319f290d7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <177bc8179be6497489c4b5b319f290d7>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:281)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 3 errors

at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x00242] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:194

at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x0007f] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:97 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

UNITY 2019.1.1f1 also i tried all 2019 versions and a lil bit of 2018, same error
http://prntscr.com/oefr11
Also i tried to change android sdk, ndk and jdk, i tried different settings in unity and same result.

I tried with a new project too! same result

EDIT: i tried to install unity to D, same shit

Comment: EDIT: Problem solved, download ndk r16b and all will be good.

Comment: If you've solved your own question, please consider posting your solution as an answer.